# Regular expression for a number field with a dash in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

Im quite bad at figuring out regular expressions for things that I need to search for.

I have this field in the format of ########**-**#.

The issue here is that there could be a maximum of 10 numbers in front of the 'dash' and between one to two numbers after the 'dash'.

How can I possibly achieve this in just regular expressions ?

Can I just do `\d{5,}-\d{1,}` ? Which says that you need at least 5 numbers in front of the dash and at least 1 after the dash ? If I do this in js do I need a special character for dash ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Specify your quantities using the `{min,max}` quantifier:

```
/\d{,10}-\d{1,2}/
```

You do not need to escape the `-` since it has no special meaning outside of character classes.

Comment: +1, although personally I'd use `\d\d?` for the second one - I don't know why, but I feel this compulsive need to make regexes as small as possible XD

Comment: @Kolink Haha nice :) I originally wrote it like that, but then I decided that this one is easier to modify for the OP should the number of digits they're trying to match change.

Answer (score 2):

```
 var m = /(\d{0,10})-(\d{1,2})/
 m[1] = // first set of numbers
 m[2] = // second set
```

Answer (score 1):

An expression like this would work:

```
\d{1,10}-\d{1,2}
```

This will match 1 to 10 digits, followed by a dash, followed by one or two additional digits.

Of course, you can replace the first quantifier with `{0,10}` or `{,10}` if you want the first set of digits to be entirely optional.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use quantifiers. Something like this will work

[0-9]{1,10}-[0-9]{1,2} or [0-9]{0,10}-[0-9]{1,2} if possible